# Using TEX in Mathtype

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

I use `Mathtype`to insert mathematical equations in MS world.
Today I understood that there's no built-in symbol for `$\mathscr(F)$` in `MathType` so I searched for a way of using `LaTex` codes in `MathType`. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bwTedwXZsg) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvIhmgGCNMw) and on [this page](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-3/tb90topping.pdf), it says that it's possible for `MathType 6` users and later to use $TEX$ in `MathType` editor.
But whenever I try, I see that `TEX` codes won't be translated and nothing happens. The version of `MathType` installed on my `windows 7x64` is `6.9a`. 
Is there anything that I should do?

**p.s.**
I have `MiKTeX 2.9`, `Texmaker` and `Word-to-LaTeX` installed on my computer.

Comment: It means that it is the time to move from MS Word to (La)TeX. You are welcome to TeX society. :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I believe the OP is entitle to three "free" curses at MSWord and/or Bill Gates before he is required to contemplate the (La)TeX alternative.

Comment: I don't have much time to learn Latex right now. because I'm busy with my thesis. I'm a bit familiar with mathematical codes for TEX because of my activity in math.stackexchange.com. Surely there should be a way. Videos by System Design Inc. on Youtube verifies that. But that way just does not work on my laptop. I'm wondering maybe I should have something installed on my system like a compiler or so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to set the preferences correctly.

In `MathType` go to "Preferences" > "Workspace preferences"
and there tick "allow TEX language entry from the keyboard".

Answer (score 0):

clc
clear all
close all
X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
Y1 = [2 3 0 2 0 7 7 6 2];
Y2 = [2 6 7 7 0 2 0 3 2];
plot(X,Y1,'r-*','LineWidth',3);
hold on
plot(X,Y2,'b-d','LineWidth',2);

> Blockquote

hold off
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y1 and Y2');
title ('Student ID = BC230213471');
legend ('My Student ID','My Student ID in reverse');

Comment: Why did you answered two times?